# Socket programing/ Signaling changes in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

Is there any way to communicate with a socket using SQL language? (Why?) Assume that, I manually open SQL Server Management Studio and open a table and then insert a record manually (by manually I want to emphasize on the absence of any middleware in between). At this moment the business demands for signaling the inserted record to another context (as either notification, or report (i.e. grid view, etc)).

The solution that I have in mind is to write the inserted record to a file and using another application monitor the file for change (Emphasizing again that I don't wanna do this through a middleware at all) , but this method is not a standard way to achieve this requirement and it is more of a workaround.

Is there any standard way to signal changes using pure SQL Server syntax/features?

Comment: You can use [SqlDependency or QueryNotifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/query-notifications-in-sql-server) to signal applications that data changes have occurred. All applications, middleware or not, communicate with SQL Server using the TDS protocol via client APIs.

Comment: @DanGuzman: Thanks, I look into it.

Comment: @DanGuzman: This is not what I asked for. This can be done in ADO.Net but IT WILL NOT WORK WHEN USING SQL MANAGEMENT STUDIO.

Comment: No need to shout. I understood your question as inserting a new row via SSMS, which would signal another context (separate application) that a change occurred. It would be the other context that would setup and subscribe to the notification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a SQLCLR routine that calls out to "something", whenever a change happens. Where I work we ue that for real-time streaming of dats from SQL Server to RabbitMQ. In your case you would have to have a trigger on the table, which calls the routine.

In our case we always change data through stored procedures, so our procedures call the SQLCLR routine.

You could also use Service Broker and External Activation. In our case we chose not to do it as the performance was not good enough.

If you want, I have a blog-post about the SQL Server -> RabbitMQ integration using SQLCLR. Obviously it doesn't have to be Rabbit, we've also done it through socket connections etc. So if you're interested, the post is [here](http://www.nielsberglund.com/2017/02/11/rabbitmq-sql-server/).

Hope this helps!

Niels